# SecureCRT and Telnet

Tags: telnet, securecrt

I am trying to connect to my local router through SecureCRT7's Telnet session. But I get "The request was refused by the remote server". However, I can Telnet using Windows' and mRemote's... So What Can I do???

Comment: Maybe print screens from settings in SecureCRT7's, would clear things up. Other than that have you set port 23? Are you using telnet protocol? Are you using outgoing firewall rules?

Comment: I disabled Comodo's Firewall and it worked like a charm. So I added a rule to Comodo and now it's working :) Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by configuring Comodo's FireWall